# ActionMappingParametersInteceptor - why do I need it

Tags: java, parameters, struts2, interceptor

I am trying to understand the use of `ActionMappingParametersInteceptor` class in Struts2.

Looking in the API:

> This interceptor sets all parameters from the action mapping, for this
>   request, on the value stack. It operates exactly like
>   `ParametersInterceptor`, only the parameters come from the
>   `ActionMapping`, not the `ActionContext.getParameters()` method.

Is there a case where an `ActionMapping` class might contain a different set of request parameters than the ones I am getting from the `ActionContext.getParameters()`?

The struts `defaultStack` of interceptors seems to be calling first the `ParametersInterceptor` and then the `ActionMappingParametersInteceptor`, but I just cannot see any reasons to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `actionMappingParams` that  extends the `params` interceptor is processing parameters from the action map using two methods that are overridden and should be overridden: `retrieveParameters` and `addParametersToContext`. First method really doing with `ActionMapping` parameters. The second is added the extra parameters to the action context.

> In this class this is a no-op, since the parameters were fetched from
>   the same location. In subclasses both `retrieveParameters()` and
>   `addParametersToContext()` should be overridden.

"no-op" means never working until

> The best way to add behavior to this interceptor is to utilize the
>   `ParameterNameAware` interface in your actions. However, if you wish
>   to apply a global rule that isn't implemented in your action, then you
>   could extend this interceptor and override the
>   `ParametersInterceptor.acceptableName(String)` method.

ParameterNameAware:

> This interface is implemented by actions that want to declare
>   acceptable parameters. Works in conjunction with
>   `ParametersInterceptor`. For example, actions may want to create a
>   whitelist of parameters they will accept or a blacklist of paramters
>   they will reject to prevent clients from setting other unexpected (and
>   possibly dangerous) parameters.

This is the only case when extra parameters could be added to the action context.